Robust and efficient offset calculation of split audio with merged audio?
I have 3 audio files (~44khz, 60min long) from a recorded meeting:
individual1-audio.mp3
individual2-audio.mp3
combined-audio.mp3

The combined audio is synchronized merged audio from both participants (generated by an external provider). The individual audio files are recorded separately per participant.
However the individual audio files are not necessarily synchronized in start time with the combined audio so they may be offset by up to 10 seconds. This means that direct anyalysis of the individual files will result in misaligned timestamps.
I am looking for an efficient algorithm to calculate the offsets in milliseconds between each individual file and the combined audio file, so that I can factor this offset into the downstream analysis eg.:
individual1-offset = +1520ms
individual2-offset = -770ms

Ideas attempted...(some chat-gpt inspired):

Computing the full cross correlation between individual* and combined and choosing the lag with the highest correlation would be optimal, but a typical file may have 150M samples making this prohibitatively expensive.

Taking a short sample of the individual file and computing the full cross correlation might work, but selecting the sample automatically is difficult.

Downsampling the files is lossy and I am unclear how this would affect the accuracy of cross correlation.


Other ideas....

Is there some efficient audio-alignment / offset-calculation algorithm I could use for this problem?

Would FFT then downsampling be more robust?

Could downsampling aggregating with min/max be less lossy for cross correlation purposes?



I don’t understand why you’d need to select the sample “automatically” to compute cross correlation on a segment of these recordings. I’m assuming the offset is constant, isn’t it? Can’t you just arbitrarily take segments from both signals with the same time stamp? Hell, just take the first 30s of data for each!

Downsampling will both help in reducing signal length and also involves anti aliasing filter (low pass filtering) the data which will most probably improve your SNR (recorded meeting im assuming mainly speech is of interest which is at lower frequencies meaning that all the high frequency content is mostly noise). And as @Jdip suggested take an arbitrary segment if still needed after downsampling

I will second @Jdip on his recommendation. I would just try to extend it a bit more. I would pick some (I would go for as many as possible) short samples (I believe 15 - 30 seconds should be fine) and calculate the cross-correlation, find the lag of the peak which corresponds to the delay and make a histogram out of them. The argument where the histogram peaks is a good candidate for the actual delay. Furthermore, if you find more than one distinct peak, it may mean that you have a variable delay (this may not be so easy to distinguish though).

@Jdip yes the offset is constant however a randomly selected sample from the individual may have silence or random background noise, and the combined audio may have the other speaker at the time leading to poor correlation.  Hilmar's solution below about selecting a high energy span could work, it needs some smarts...

I think cross correlation is they way to go here. You don't need to correlate the entire files. Assuming that the sync error is constant and doesn't drift, you only need to correlate over a lag range that's sufficiently larger than max offset.
Here is one method

Chop the first few minutes of individual 1 into 30 second frames.
Choose the frame with the highest energy (other than the first)
Cross correlate that frame with a 90 second snippet of the combined signal centered around the center of the frame chosen in step 2. The peak of the cross correlation should give you the time offset.

This method can be refined by looking for frames that have higher energy in individual 1 and low in individual 2 (and vice versa).

Thanks makes sense. I'm going to test this approach against STFT -> cross correlation and will post results here....
